# ggplot facet with multiple boolean columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, boolean, subset

I have a dataframe with a column for dates, a column for values and about half a dozen boolean columns:

```
date        value         x1    x0    x2    x3 ....
01/1999     2000          TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE
02/1999     5000          FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE
02/1999     6000          FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE
03/1999     5000          TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Now I would like to plot the count of each entry of date for each column x1, x0 ... :
I can easily do that by subsetting the dataframe and calling ggplot each time:

```
ggplot(subset, aes(date)) + geom_bar()
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way to generate a single plot with facets, with 6 subplots each filtered for x1, x2, x3 = TRUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may wish to convert the data frame from wide to long format, with all the boolean columns gathered into a single column. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(subset.variable, logic, -date, -value) %>%
  filter(logic) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, value)) +
  geom_point() +                # using geom_point for illustration
  facet_wrap(~subset.variable)
```

[image: plot]

Sample data used:

```
set.seed(123)
n = 200
df <- data.frame(
  date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("1999-01-01"),
                  to = as.Date("1999-01-01") + n - 1,
                  by = 1),
  value = rpois(n, lambda = 2),
  x1 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace = T),
  x2 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace = T),
  x3 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace = T),
  x4 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace = T),
  x5 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace = T),
  x6 = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace = T)
)

> head(df)
        date value    x1    x2    x3    x4    x5    x6
1 1999-01-01     1  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
2 1999-01-02     3 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
3 1999-01-03     2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
4 1999-01-04     4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
5 1999-01-05     4  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
6 1999-01-06     0 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```